# rsyslog filtering based on message content

Tags: log-files, rsyslog

I have an application which is writing to syslog. The messages written to the syslog are for various buckets which need to be filtered out. Every message starts with a bucket number, so the messages are written as:

```
1: Message for bucket 1
14: Message for bucket 14
123: Message for bucket 123
```

I want to filter these messages based on the bucket number, which I suppose can be done with a regex. These buckets are numeric and can be in the range 1-999. The output for these buckets should go different files, one for each bucket. For the above example, it should be:

```
/var/log/myapp/1.log
/var/log/myapp/14.log
/var/log/myapp/123.log
```

Can someone help me with how this can be done with rsyslog?

Answer (score 5):

I do a simple filter in the rsyslog config.

In mine it would look like this:

```
:msg, contains, "123: Message for bucket 123" -/var/log/myapp/123.log
```

This will search the msg property of incoming syslog messages for that string, and log it to the file I specify.

If you want to learn more about configuring rsyslog in here is an excellent place to start: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html

Comment: Then, I need 999 lines in the configuration file.

Comment: Problem is that does not account for case, what if you are looking for: Error or error or ERROR?

Comment: It works for me but the same logs get printed in all the log files

Comment: I have been doing this Linux and OpenSource thing for about 20 years and I have yet to encounter anything more frustrating and not helpful as the rsyslog documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I guess I am a bit late with this answer, but actually rsyslog lets you create log file names dynamically, so you could create a template that constructs the log file name based on the msg contents, using either *field.number* or *regex.submatch* properties to extract the bucket number - see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/templates.html for details.

However, is you are happy with the 999 lines, it is certainly simpler, and the matter addressed by Ronaldo Nascimento can be taken care of by using *contains_i* instead of *contains* - *contains_i* is case insensitive.